# Buscar en un campo un dato especifico de la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

Intento seleccionar un dato especifico en un campo de la base de datos, en este caso tengo un campo que se llama `idDepto` y tiene almacenados los valores `3,4,5,6,7,8` pero al momento de ejecutar la consulta:

```
$sql = "SELECT Correo, idDepto, Notificacion
        FROM notificaciones
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET =  " . $_POST['id_depto'] . ",idDepto";
```

Al momento de ejecutar la consulta anterior no me aparecen resultados, y bueno decidi utilizer find_in_set porque me funciono bien en MySQL, esta consulta la ejecute en MySQL y si me arroja los resultados.

```
  SELECT `Correo`, `idDepto`, `Notificacion` 
  FROM `notificaciones` 
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(5, idDepto)
```

Comment: Puede que te falten los parentesis, `FIND_IN_SET(" . $_POST['id_depto'] . ",idDepto)";` Recuerda que es una función.

Comment: Tienes un = en lugar de los paréntesis, puedes hacer un echo de la variable $sql para ver como queda construida la sentencia.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Edu3D por tu pronta respuesta, si era eso, ya lo ejecuta perfecto, y una disculpa es la primera vez que lo utilizo, era utilizar `find_in_set` o `in` .

Comment: @Carmen ya lo corregi, muchas gracias

Comment: @Edu3D deberias dejarla como respuesta para que otras personas resuelvan un problema similar

Comment: @sioesi Ya se me adelantaron ^^, la próxima lo pondré como respuesta.

Comment: jajaja si, con tu respuesta xD @Edu3D saludos!

Comment: xD igualmente gracias @Edu3D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solucion Rapida

Cambia tu consulta por la siguiente:

```
$sql = "SELECT Correo, idDepto, Notificacion
        FROM notificaciones
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(" . $_POST['id_depto'] . ", idDepto)";
```

De acuerdo a lo que tu nos comentas, la funcion `FIND_IN_SET` de MySQL, necesita que se usen `()`, dejandola de la siguiente manera:

```
FIND_IN_SET()
```

Mas en el ejemplo que tu planteas, esta quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET =  5,idDepto
```

Por lo tanto, basta con que elimines el `=` y agregues los parentesis en la consulta.

### [Ejemplo en linea!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLSwEIVOID/INDopUyU@JTUgtK8pViFWwVTK2hksWFOUCuUrCrj6tziIJzflFRar6OQmaKC0ipjoJffklmWmZyYnJmfh5YAwy4Bfn7KuQhyaYWo8iHe7gGuSq4efq5xHv6xQe7hmgoKejB3KIOc4t6LFBQCW6fphLUWQVFmXklYMcBBezt/v8HAA)

---

#### Nota

> Como sugerencia, y por medidas de seguridad en tu codigo, es recomendable **no acceder a las variables POST y GET de manera directa**. En su defecto es mejor usar la funcion **[filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php)**.

Lo que dejaria tu codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

    $id_depto = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "id_depto", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $sql = "SELECT Correo, idDepto, Notificacion
            FROM notificaciones
            WHERE FIND_IN_SET(" . $id_depto . ", idDepto)";

?>
```

Aunque **existen mejores practicas**, como por ejemplo las consultas preparadas *(prepared statements)*, esta que te planteo te puede ayudar a proteger un poco de lo que corresponde a SQL Injection o de caracteres no deseados. Ya que esta se encarga de filtrar los caracteres que llegan tanto por `POST` como por `GET`.